# Lower bound for the size of a product-set

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, additive-combinatorics

I recently realised (rather late in life) that I don't have a good grasp of the following:

> Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian group and let $A, B$ be **subsets** of $G$. (Neither $A$ nor $B$ is required to be a subgroup.) How small
> can $|AB|$ be?

By $AB$ here I mean the set $AB = \{ab : a \in A, \, b \in B\}$. I impose the condition that $G$ be non-abelian because if $G$ is abelian then we have an answer to the question. This is known as [Kneser's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser%27s_theorem_(combinatorics)) and states that (in multiplicative notation):

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and let $A, B$ be subsets of $G$.
> Then $$|AB| \geqslant |A|+|B| - |H(AB)|,$$ where $H(AB) := \{g \in G : g(AB) = AB\}$ is the so-called stabiliser of the subset $AB$.

Is there anything known about this question? For example, does Kneser's theorem fail for non-abelian groups?

---

1. Kneser's theorem, as I have stated it (and restricted to the setting
   of finite groups), is (I think) equivalent to the statement that
   appears on Wikipedia.
2. There exist easy (and silly) answers to the question. For instance,
   one could say that $|AB| \geq |A|, |B|$ and thus  $|AB| \geq
       \max\{|A|, |B|\}$. I am not interested in something like that.

Comment: A partial answer (not as strong as the form of Kneser's theorem you've given) is the Cauchy-Davenport inequality, generalised to non-abelian groups. E.g. Karolyi and Wheeler (independently) showed that if every non-trivial subgroup of $G$ has size $\geq \lvert A\rvert+\lvert B\rvert-1$ then $\lvert AB\rvert \geq \lvert A\rvert+\lvert B\rvert - 1$. See e.g. https://cds.cern.ch/record/904813/files/cer-002575022.pdf

Comment: The introduction to Karolyi's paper linked in my previous comment contains references to other papers that have studied this problem, and should  be a good starting point for investigation.

Comment: @ThomasBloom Many thanks. I'll have a look. (It already says there that there is no analogue of Kneser's theorem for non-abelian groups.)

Comment: A [147 page preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.0096) by Matt DeVos classifies all pairs $A, B$ of finite subsets of groups satisfying $|AB| < |A| + |B|$.

Comment: Right. So it's nothing short of a whole research field.

Comment: I read lots of different things, but: it seems that there is an analogue of Kneser's theorem for non-abelian groups. Olson ("On the Sum of Two Sets in a Group") writes that Kemperman proved the following: if $A$, $B$ are subsets of the finite group $G$ and if $a_0$, $b_0$ are in $A$ and $B$ respectively, then there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $|AB| \geq |A| + |B| - |H|$ and $H \subseteq a_0^{-1} A B b_0^{-1} := C$. The problem with this inequality is, presumably, that $|C|$ may be large for all choices of  $a_0$, $b_0$ and thus the quantity $|A| + |B| - |H|$ may be small...